# What happen for Order prices if we change default currency?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

If i change default currency in PrestaShop 1.6 it say you have to change manually each product's price. but my question is what happen for stored order prices in database?
with change default currency what affect on previous saved Order price?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen for previous orders. Each order stores its own informations in database and is never edited afterward. There's absolutely no risk for changing default currency.